# How to interpret the output of perf tool

Tags: perf

I get below output from the `perf` tool on linux.

Take `page-faults` for example, what does `(99.99%)` mean here?
Thank you.

```
 8,650,693,659      cache-references                                              (49.96%)
     1,775,706,317      cache-misses              #   20.527 % of all cache refs      (50.05%)
 1,738,355,037,627      cycles                                                        (50.10%)
 2,031,670,462,762      instructions              #    1.17  insn per cycle           (50.11%)
   325,348,135,322      branches                                                      (50.02%)
         1,064,589      faults
            12,767      migrations
     3,244,576,263      branch-misses             #    1.00% of all branches          (49.97%)
         1,064,661      page-faults                                                   (99.99%)
```

Comment: The numbers in parens at the far right are what happens when there weren't enough hardware PMUs to count all the events at the same time: it multiplexes them and averages / extrapolates.  But page-faults is a software event; the kernel keeps its own counter for that.  IDK why perf would print a 99.99% there instead of leaving that column empty for that event like mine does.  (`6.0.g4fe89d07dcc2` on x86-64 Linux 6.0.8-arch1-1).  That's the only mysterious thing here, but you seem to be asking more generally.  IDK what parts you *do* understand, so hard to know where to start.

Comment: I assume you know what a page-fault *is*, and some CPU-architecture and OS basics; if not, see http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ and https://agner.org/optimize/ for the CPU architecture parts, and the explanations of the events in `perf list`.